# Undefined variable: categories / getting this error after clearing route

Tags: laravel

I am using this route to get common instances for all my routes :

```
View::composer('*', 'App\Http\Controllers\Master@all');
```

And in my controller

```
public function all($view){
    $general = General::where('id',1)->first();
    $footer = Footer::where('id',1)->first();
    $navmenu = Navmenu::with('submenus')->where('status',1)->get();
    $socials = Social::where('status',1)->get();
    $categories = Category::where('status',1)->get();
    $footer_about = FooterLinkAbout::where('status',1)->take(5)->get();
    $footer_explore = FooterLinkExplore::where('status',1)->take(5)->get();
    $footer_cat = Footer_link_category::where('status',1)->take(5)->get();
    $fund_raised = Transection::all();
    $languages = Language::where('status',1)->get();
    $ip = '43.250.81.202';
    $arr_ip = geoip()->getLocation($ip);
    $user_location = $arr_ip->country; // get a country
    // $main_currency = Currency::where('status',1)->get();
    $currencies = Currency::where('status',1)- 
    >where('session_currency','!=',Session::get('currency_c'))->get();
    $user_currency = Currency::where('session_currency',Session::get('currency_c'))->first();
    
    $currency_by_location = Currency::where('status',1)->where('country_name',$user_location)- 
    >first();

    $view->with('general',$general)->with('footer',$footer)->with('navmenu',$navmenu)- 
    >with('socials',$socials)->with('categories',$categories)->with('footer_about',$footer_about)- 
    >with('footer_explore',$footer_explore)->with('footer_cat',$footer_cat)- 
    >with('languages',$languages)->with('currencies',$currencies)- 
    >with('user_currency',$user_currency)->with('currency_by_location',$currency_by_location)- 
    >with('fund_raised',$fund_raised);
}
```

But after clearing the routes using following codes :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

I am getting the following error :

[image]

Comment: What happens if you switch to this? Do you see the data you expect? This is a good starting point to debug the problem, starting with understanding if this code is being executed at all.

public function all($view){
  
    $categories = Category::where('status',1)->get();
dd($categories);
  }

Comment: It gives the same error, the code is not executing I guess

Comment: can I use multiple view::composer  ?